# Username and password are incorrect

Tags: active-directory, password

I have a domain organization with windows 7 computers.
From time to time
users can not seem to log on, the error message is
**"Username and password are incorrect"**

The password used *is* the correct one.  Only after the computer is restarted does the login work.

Comment: Capslock/Numslock

Answer (score 0):

Try having them use the domain name when logging on.

So, instead of logging as **'username'** with the password 'pass', let them try use **'YourDomain\username'** and 'pass' instead.

Comment: I tried but it's not work

Comment: Do the computers with this problem use sleep mode when the problem occurs ? Can you check if you have traffic packet loss between the computers and domain server ?